# Mass edit in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say you have some products which have 2 fields, a description and a stock value.

How do you layout a form of all the products in an action named mass_edit with fields so a user can edit some, press submit and then save them in a mass_update?

I have used nested forms in a order-order_line scenario but i can't seem to figure this one out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following screencasts can help you to find a solution:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually

Comment: Wish these great screencasts would come bakc